# Yii2 Toggle Button and Modal not working

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

I created a website using yii2 framework. But i have a problem in modal and toggle button. This is my scenario, My modal is working but when i minimize it the toggle button is not working. When i delete the jquery in my AppAsset the toggle button will work but the modal and the other extension like dtPicker, dropdown, etc.. won't work. And if i put the jquery and delete the bootstrap.js the toggle button will work also but the others not. And if i delete both same result.

Any idea guys? Please help me. TIA

This is my AppAsset:

```
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
public $basePath = '@webroot';
public $baseUrl = '@web';
public $css = [

    'css/CssIsLife.css',
    'css/siteforever.css',
    'css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css',

    ];

   public $js = [
    'js/jquery.js',
    'js/jquery.easing.min.js',
    'js/custom.js',
    'js/bootstrap.js',
    'js/sadlife.js',
    'js/scrollreveal.min.js',
    'js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js',
    'js/creative.min.js',
    'js/modal.js',
];

public $depends = [
   'yii\web\JqueryAsset',
    'yii\web\YiiAsset',
    'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset',
];

}
```

Comment: can you tell me which exactly which js file you don't want in that particular page ? bootstrap.js or jquery.js ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to do anything with AppAsset.php

Just go on your view page an try following.

```
unset($this->assetBundles['yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset']); // disable bootstrap.js also in this case


unset($this->assetBundles['yii\web\JqueryAsset']); // disable jquery.js also in this case
```

**or Else**
You may try this also

```
if(($key = array_search('js-filepath/file.js', $this->js)) !== false) {
                    unset($this->js[$key]);
   }
```

Comment: My pleasure. :)